# android AOSP music player source code not building

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mediaplayer, android-source

i am new to android .so i am trying to do a very simple task. i just want to test out the stock music player app in my emulator by downloading the source code. But every time i try to build it it spits out errors. I tried to build codes from both github's android [page](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music) as well as http://source.android.com.i have also tried various different releases but still same results.

[image: here are the files that spit out the errors]
[image]

any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: the error is "your project contains errors please fix it before running it". it comes up as a pop out.
i have added the error log image in the post if its of any help . sorry i am new to android . hope some of it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are compiling against `Android-16` or newer since some the classes/API's are only available on `Android-16`. The errors you posted look like eclipse errors to me. They do not seem to be related to the project at all. Try restarting your eclipse and do a clean build.